# CNAME for A record via Subdomain ignored

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4

i try to do the following:

```
@ A example.org
www CNAME myotherexample.org.
```

and in the index.php for example.org:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.org");
die();
```

This should actually work but it doesn't.
The DNS entry for myotherexample.org reads as followed:

```
*.myotherexample.com A SERVERIP
```

The vHost definition für myotherexample reads like this:

```
ServerName awesome.myotherexample.org
ServerAlias *.myotherexample.org
```

Every request to myexample.org is redirected to www.myexample.org (so far so good) but then ends app requesting the Apache server on the same server but without a virtual host request. I log vhost access to a combined log but the request for www.example.org shows up in the general apache log, so no vHost got the request.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: `A` records ONLY take an IP address as the RR Data (not `example.org` as you have in your first line of config)

Comment: Sorry, it is an IP adress actually :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't configured the `NameVirtualHost *:80` / `NameVirtualHost *:443` statement in Apache (assumming that this hasn't changed in 2.4 -- I only have experience with 2.2).

Does a `dig` or `host` show what you would expect?

Anything further would require to see some Apache config and some output from `dig`, `host`, or `nslookup`.